# Having trouble with Lemma 3 of Hanson's proof that $\prod\limits_{p^a \le n} p^a < 3^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I have been going through [Hanson's proof](https://books.google.com/books?id=mClZ1nGtyswC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=Hanson+on+the+product+of+primes&source=bl&ots=I4lPYc-DF0&sig=YqlgegGXoZVuSHCk5bNb1CjWM7k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic_eTY3t_dAhXRFjQIHfALD-wQ6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 33-37) and I was following it up until Lemma 3.

There, Hanson does a magic trick which I am not clear on.

Here is the step:

$$\frac{(n/a_i)^{n/a_i}}{((n-a_i+1)/a_i)^{(n-a_i+1)/a_i}} = \left(1+\frac{1}{(n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1)}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i - 1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\frac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}$$

If anyone could help me understand how these values are equal, I would appreciate it.

---

Edit 1:

With help, I was able to figure it out.  Here's what I came up with.

$\dfrac{(n/a_i)^{n/a_i}}{((n-a_i+1)/a_i)^{(n-a_i+1)/a_i}} = \dfrac{(n/a_i)^{(n-a_i+1)/a_i}}{((n-a_i+1)/a_i)^{(n-a_i+1)/a_i}}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$

$\left(\dfrac{(n/a_i)}{((n-a_i +1)/a_i)}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$

$\left(\dfrac{n}{n-a_i +1}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$

$\left(\dfrac{(n-a_i+1) + (a_i - 1)}{n-a_i +1}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$

$\left(\dfrac{(n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1) + 1}{(n-a_i +1)/(a_i-1)}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$

$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{(n-a_i +1)/(a_i-1)}\right)^{((n-a_i+1)/(a_i-1))\times((a_i-1)/a_i)}\left(\dfrac{n}{a_i}\right)^{(a_i-1)/a_i}=$